# How to set Vi mode in terminal permanently ? Ubuntu

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu, terminal, vi

I wonder how can I set up vi mode for using in terminal permanently, when I set `set -o vi on` it works fine  until I restart the terminal. Maybe I can configure it through config file directrly, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
set -o vi
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. It seems like I should learn more about bash